# Right way for wiring backbone views

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

```
I have a two views:
   1 LeftView (maximized when RightView is minimized & vice versa)
   2 RightView (containing)
      - collection of 
         - RightItemView (rendering RightItemModel)
```

When RightView is maximized and the user clicks a RightItemView, I want to maximize LeftView and display something according to the data from the clicked RightItemView.

What's the proper way to wire them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the Backbone.Events module:

http://backbonejs.org/#Events

Basically, this line is all it takes to create your event dispatcher:

```
var dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events);
```

Then all of your views can trigger/listen for events using the global dispatcher.

So, in RightItemView you would do something like this in the click event:

```
dispatcher.trigger('rightItemClick', data); // data is whatever you need the LeftView to know
```

Then, in LeftView's initialize function, you can listen for the event and call your relevant function:

```
dispatcher.on('rightItemClick', this.maximizeAndDisplayData);
```

Assuming your LeftView would have a function like so:

```
maximizeAndDisplayData: function(data) {
    // do whatever you need to here
    // data is what you passed with the event
}
```

Comment: Thanks jordanj77 I will go with your approach, though the Ganeshji & nameIsNull look good too. Too bad I don't have reputation to share.

Answer (score 2):

The solution @jordanj77 mentioned is definitely one of the correct ways to achieve your requirement. Just out of curiosity, I thought of another way to achieve the same effect. Instead of using a separate `EventDispatcher` to communicate between the two views, why shouldn't we use the underlying model as our `EventDispatcher`? Let's try to think in those lines.

To start with, add a new `boolean` attribute to the `RightItem` model called `current` and default it to `false`. Whenever, the user selects the `RightItemView`, set the model's `current` attribute to true. This will trigger a `change:current` event on the model.

```
var RightItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    current: false,
  }
});

var RightItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click li': 'changeCurrent'
  }

  changeCurrent: function() {
    this.model.set('current', true);
  }
});
```

On the other side, the `LeftView` will be handed a Backbone.Collection of `RightItem` models during creation time. You would anyways have this instance to supply the `RightView` isn't it? In its initialize method, the `LeftView` will listen for `change:current` event. When the event occurs, `LeftView` will change the `current` attribute of the model it is currently displaying to false and start displaying the new model that triggered this event.

```
var LeftView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('change:current', this.render, this);
  },

  render: function(model) {
    // Avoid events triggered when resetting model to false
    if(model.get('current') === true) {

      // Reset the currently displayed model
      if (this.model) {
        this.model.set('current') = false;
      }

      // Set the currently selected model to the view
      this.model = model;

      // Display the view for the current model
    }
  }
});

var leftView = new LeftView({
  // Use the collection that you may have given the RightView anyways
  collection: rightItemCollection 
});
```

This way, we get to use the underlying model as the means of communication between the Left and Right Views instead of using an `EventDispatcher` to broker for us.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @Ganeshji inspired me to make a live [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/br0AfG?p=preview)

I've created 2 views for this.

```
var RightView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('.right_view'),

  template: _.template('<p>Right View</p>'),

  renderTemplate: function () {
      this.$el.html('');
      this.$el.append(this.template());  
      this.$link = this.$el.append('<a href="#" title="some data" id="left_view_max">Item to view</a>').children('#left_view_max'); 
  },

  events: {
      'click #left_view_max'    :   'maxLeftView'
  },

  maxLeftView: function () {
    //triggering the event for the leftView
    lView.trigger('displayDataInLeftView', this.$link.attr('title'));
  },

  initialize: function (options) {  
      this.renderTemplate();
  }
});

var LeftView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('.left_view'),

  template: _.template('<p>Left View</p>'),

  renderTemplate: function () {
      this.$el.html('');
      this.$el.append(this.template());
  },

  displayDataInLeftView: function (data) {
    this.$el.append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
  },

  initialize: function (options) {
    //set the trigger callback
    this.on('displayDataInLeftView', this.displayDataInLeftView, this);
    this.renderTemplate(); 
  }
});

 var lView = new LeftView();
 var rView = new RightView();
```

Hope this helps.